# Why count gives different result that row_num in window function with only order by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

On a temp table:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  a|
|  4|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  2|  b|
|  4|  b|
|  2|  c|
|  4|  c|
|  3|  d|
|  4|  e|
+---+---+
```

I was expecting count(*) to give a similar result to row_number(), given that default for range is current row and unbounded preceding. But that is clearly not the case.

```
select a,b,
count(*) over ( order by b) cnt,
row_number() over ( order by b) rnum
from x
```

```
+---+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|cnt|rnum|
+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  a|  3|   1|
|  2|  a|  3|   2|
|  4|  a|  3|   3|
|  1|  b|  6|   4|
|  2|  b|  6|   5|
|  4|  b|  6|   6|
|  2|  c|  8|   7|
|  4|  c|  8|   8|
|  3|  d|  9|   9|
|  4|  e| 10|  10|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Why is count(*) grouping results for each `b`? Does it work like rank()?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am actually using Spark.

Comment: @Zhorov thanks, seems like it is something about range vs rows

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server please tag only the correct RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, just compare the difference between the `range` and `row` keywords.

```
create table #temp(a int, b varchar(16))
insert into #temp(a, b)
values   (1, 'a')
       , (2, 'a')
       , (4, 'a')
       , (1, 'b')
       , (2, 'b')
       , (4, 'b')
       , (2, 'c')
       , (4, 'c')
       , (3, 'd')
       , (4, 'e')

select * from #temp

select a, b
       , count(*) over (order by b range between unbounded preceding and current row) cnt1
       , count(*) over (order by b rows  between unbounded preceding and current row) cnt2
       , row_number() over (order by b) rnum
from #temp
```

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a9c5404a182ae4dba7ae0576d9519cd) for your query.  Good answer +1.

Answer (score -1):

In which order are you placing similar values like :

3

3

3

?

Because there is no difference between similar values, the count will be global to the ORDER BY subclause of the OVER

Comment: Thanks, so is it like it partitions by for each similar value? i.e if values are like 3,3,3,4,4 then it will give 3,3,3,5,5?

Comment: I found out that default `range` clubs together the rows with ties. Thanks for your answer, it helped me in right direction.